# Is it bad practice to use hidden fields with a CompareValidator?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to validate a box to only accept dates that are greater than today, I was thinking of using CompareValidator that would compare with a hidden field that contains today's date.

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Not really `bad practice` but there are better and easier ways to do so.

The question is, **what** are you going to do with that input. If you somehow store it or handle it *server-side*, you **have to** validate it not only *client-side* but also on your server.

If you passed a model to your view, use Data Annotations to validate the fields. Take a quick look at this great [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner).